What plot type to use for heatmap-like data with variations?
I have a heatmap-like data as shown in the picture below.
These data is a measurement result for one sample. I have many samples of the same kind and hence, same sort of data.
Instead of plotting such heatmap for each sample, I would like to plot a single heatmap but with inclusion of statistical/variation information (or at least the error bars) inside each heatmap's square/point.
So perhaps I should be looking for a different sort of plot, not the heatmap. Any suggestion is welcome.
P.S. The heatmap below is generated using Python and seaborn, but at this point it does not really matter.

